# Undefined reference to void functions from a header file

Tags: c++, function, header-files

I am trying to reduce the length of a long function by splitting it up into smaller components, but I encounter the error 'undefined reference to `Pawn::generateCaptureMoves(Pawn, ...) const'` , `Pawn::generateForwardMoves(Pawn, ...) const'`, `Pawn::generateEnPassantMoves(Pawn, ...) const'` when I try to compile my file.

### Pawn.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Piece.h"
#include <vector>

// Represents a pawn
struct Pawn : public Piece {
    Pawn(Team, int, int); // Constructor

    moveTypes calcPossibleMoves(Piece*[8][8]) const override;
    void generateCaptureMoves(Pawn p, moveTypes moves, Piece*[8][8], int) const;
    void generateForwardMoves(Pawn p, moveTypes moves, Piece*[8][8], int) const;
    void generateEnPassantMoves(Pawn p, moveTypes moves, Piece*[8][8]) const;

};
```

### Pawn.cpp

```
#include "Pawn.h"
#include <vector>

Pawn::Pawn(Team team, int xPos, int yPos): Piece(team, xPos, yPos, PieceType::PAWN, "p") {}

moveTypes Pawn::calcPossibleMoves(Piece* board[8][8]) const {
    moveTypes moves;
    int dir = (getTeam() == Team::WHITE)? -1: 1;
    int xPos = getX(), yPos = getY();

    generateCaptureMoves(*this, moves, board, dir);
    generateForwardMoves(*this, moves, board, dir);
    generateEnPassantMoves(*this, moves, board);

    return moves;
};

void generateCaptureMoves(Pawn p, moveTypes moves, Piece* board[8][8], int dir) {
    // (...)
}

void generateForwardMoves(Pawn p, moveTypes moves, Piece* board[8][8], int dir){
    // (...)

}

void generateEnPassantMoves(Pawn p, moveTypes moves, Piece* board[8][8]){
    // (...)
}
```

---

### Things I have tried

- removing the `const` keyword on the void function in the header file
- adding const keyword on the functions inside the *.cpp* file
- removing `const` keyword and replacing with `{}`

I am at a loss for ideas, can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: You are missing the class scope `Pawn::` when you define the functions.

Comment: You're defining the function as *free functions* in the .cpp file instead of as member functions since you've not used `Pawn::`. You must be in the scope of the class to define them as member functions.